# Delete key from S3 using boto command line tools

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I want to delete a key from s3 using boto command line tools, but i cannot find any command in the documentation

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commandline.html

is there any way to delete a key from s3 using boto command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a delete method as part of the boto.s3 module. Once you have a key object, you can removed the key with delete.

(keep in mind, if you have versioning turned on, there will be a version of it left for the lifecycle settings - if you don't know what that means, you likely do not need to worry about it)

here is an example:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
s3conn = S3Connection()  # assumes you have a /etc/boto.cfg or .boto
bucket = s3conn.get_bucket('bucket-name-here')
bucket.get_all_keys()   # this shows all the keys - only for demo purp.
bucket.get_key('full_key_path_name').delete()
bucket.get_all_keys()   # thos shows all the keys - sans the one you deleted
```

demo:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection()
>>> s3 = S3Connection()
>>> bucket = s3.get_bucket('cgseller-test')
>>> bucket.get_all_keys()
[<Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/else>, <Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file>, <Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file1>, <Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file2>, <Key: cgseller-test,test>]
>>> bucket.get_key('newfolder/else').delete()
<Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/else>
>>> bucket.get_all_keys()
[<Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file>, <Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file1>, <Key: cgseller-test,newfolder/file2>, <Key: cgseller-test,test>]
```

Comment: You mean like   aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/test2.txt  ?   That is not a boto command that is the aws command.